# Vertically align minipages within a minipage - top and center

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I am struggling with creating an interface like this one below.

So basically, I have a couple of sections on the page that have to have a set height (10cm) (which are defined as a minipage) and within each of these section there are "kind of" 2 columns: the left one containing some other minipages/text that has to be aligned vertically on top, one below each other, and the right one which has to be centered vertically. If neither the picture, nor the text take up the whole height of the section, there should be a white field, as I said, the height is always 10cm.
[image]

I tried some approaches, but:

1) 
when defining the outer minipage as:

```
  \begin{minipage}[c][9cm]{0.3\textwidth},
```

all the elements (the left column too) were aligned vertically

2)
when i left the top line as in full code snippet below, as [t] so that the inner minipages get aligned to center by default, The image was aligned with the middle of the left column, not the middle of the whole section:

[image: Not what I wanted]

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
  \nonstopmode
  \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{
   papersize={216mm, 303mm},
   left=0mm,
   top=0mm,
   bottom=0mm,
   right=0mm
   }

  \usepackage[x-1]{pdfx}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{changepage}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}



  \begin{document}



  \newgeometry{
  left=3mm,
  top=3mm,
  bottom=3mm,
  right=3mm
  }

    \begin{minipage}[c][9cm]{0.3\textwidth}
      \parbox[t][0cm][b]{5cm}{\textcolor{black}{\Large TITLE}}
       \begin{adjustwidth}{0mm}{5mm}
       problems???
       \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[c][9cm]{0.7\textwidth}
    \vspace{5pt}
      \begin{center}
      \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}%
      \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (X) at (0,0){
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=12cm,height=8.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-golden}
      };%

      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}

    \end{minipage}%

      \textcolor{black}{\hrulefill}

    \begin{minipage}[c][9cm]{0.7\textwidth}
      \begin{center}
      \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}%
      \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (X) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=13cm,height=8.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-golden}};%

      \begin{scope}[x={(X.south east)},y={(X.north west)}]%

      \node[anchor=north west,text width=0.08\textwidth,inner sep=2mm, fill=black,draw,color=black] (Z) at (0.9, 1) {%
          \centering
          \textcolor{white}{\huge info}\par%
      };

      \end{scope}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}

    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[c][9cm]{0.27\textwidth}


      \parbox[t][0cm][b]{3.8cm}{\textcolor{black}{\Large  rafal}}

      \begin{flushleft}
      \begin{adjustwidth}{0mm}{7mm}
      dfakpjfldsa . dfklaljkdfa dfkjfd dfaskjdfs dfjkadfa fdnjkfd dfandfs df njkdfa dfk ds sd . a . dsafkjweL,M DF LDAKDFLKAKLFJFD KLKk
      \end{adjustwidth}
      \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}


      \textcolor{black}{\hrulefill}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please make your snippet compilable, i.e. start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am not familiar with the \veryHuge font size.   Also, try to use generic images like `example-image`.

Comment: I edited my code snippet with generic images and all the package info necessary to generate the image. I didn't find any panorama-like image though, which would best exemplify the problem.

Comment: Also if you have any  other suggestions as to how to achieve the layout I want to achieve, please share :) I am aware that my current solution is not the neatest one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to have understood your request, however I suggest to you to use `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    papersize={216mm, 303mm},
    left=0mm,
    top=0mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    right=0mm
}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\newtcolorbox{myframebox}[1][]{height=10cm, colback=white, sidebyside, sidebyside align=top seam, lower separated=false,sidebyside gap=10pt,#1}
\newtcolorbox{mytextbox}{colback=green!40!white,width=\linewidth}
\newtcolorbox{myimagebox}{colback=white,width=12.1cm, height=(10cm-6mm), valign=center, nobeforeafter, boxsep=0pt, 
leftrule=-1pt,rightrule=-1pt, bottomrule=-1pt, toprule=-1pt,
left=0pt, right=0pt, bottom=0pt, top=0pt}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{
        left=3mm,
        top=3mm,
        bottom=3mm,
        right=3mm
    }
\begin{myframebox}[righthand width=12cm]
    \begin{mytextbox}
        problems???
    \end{mytextbox}
    \begin{mytextbox}
        If ``problems???''\ is the title you could put
        just one titled tcolorbox here
    \end{mytextbox}

       \tcblower
    \begin{myimagebox}
        \includegraphics[width=12cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-golden}
    \end{myimagebox}
\end{myframebox}

\begin{myframebox}[lefthand width=12cm]
    \begin{myimagebox}
        \includegraphics[width=12cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-golden}
    \end{myimagebox}
    \tcblower
    \begin{mytextbox}
        \Large  rafal
    \end{mytextbox}
    \begin{mytextbox}
        dfakpjfldsa . dfklaljkdfa dfkjfd dfaskjdfs dfjkadfa fdnjkfd dfandfs df njkdfa dfk ds sd . a . dsafkjweL,M DF LDAKDFLKAKLFJFD KLKk
    \end{mytextbox}
\end{myframebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]